# how to conditionally hide a row in excel if condition is not met

Tags: xml, excel, bi-publisher

I am using BI Publisher add-in in excel ,
and I want to hide a row of `<?net_salary?>` if the value equal 0 
my code :

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(.//NET_SALARY) != 0"><xsl:value-of select="(.//NET_SALARY)"/></xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>   
    ** hide row **
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put an `IF` statement at the beginning of the row before anything else, and then `end if` at the end of the row after everything else, it will not render the row if the condition is not met. For more information, there's details in the BI Publisher Report Designer guide on IF statements.

Example:

`<?if:net_salary<>'0'?>`Table cells and data elements`<?end if?>`